# Azure Text-to-Speech SDK vs API: when to use which?

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-speech

I’m new to using Azure Cognitive Services (and programming in general).
The Azure Text to Speech service is provided through two interfaces: the Speech SDK and the REST API. I was wondering when one should choose to use the SDK or REST API? What are the advantages of the SDK over the API, and vice versa?
The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-sdk) of the Azure Speech SDK is quite vague on this. It says:

> In some cases, you can't or shouldn't use the Speech SDK. In those cases, you can use REST APIs to access the Speech service. For example, use the Speech-to-text REST API v3.0 for batch transcription and custom speech.

For context, I’m looking to implement an text-to-speech application that takes a JSON of conversation strings, synthesizes each string to a speech file and saves it to cloud storage. So far I've been using the Speech SDK locally and have managed to save speech files to local storage, but I need to do this in the cloud.

Let me know if I should provide more details and thanks in advance for any insight!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation refers to the REST API use in case you want to transcribe or synthesize speech in batch mode, ie, not in real-time. If you want real-time transcription or synthesis results, you shall use SDK APIs.

See the overview of text to speech APIs including links to specific documentation for batch and real-time https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/text-to-speech